# iPad: gesture recognizer on left/right side of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm working on a GLKViewController based game which interprets taps and swipes as game controls. I want to support two-player mode by letting the first player tap or swipe on the left side of the screen, and letting the second player tap or swipe on the right side of the screen. In a perfect world, I'd like the gesture recognizers to work even if the swipes are sloppy and go past the centerline of the screen (with the starting point of the swipe being used to determine which player gets the input).

What would be the best way to implement this? Can I lay down a gesture recognizer on the left half of the screen, and another one on the right side of the screen? Will two separate recognizers work properly together even if both sides are being tapped/swiped rapidly at the same time? Or should I create a full-screen recognizer and parse the swipes and taps entirely on my own? I don't have experience with gesture recognizers so I don't know what the preferred approach is or how well they work when you have more than one being swiped on simultaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making two UIViews overlaid on top of my GLKView, one on the left side of the screen and one on the right. Each view has a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` (the long-press recognizer is basically a more flexible tap—I needed to use it to reject some gestures from being interpreted both as a pan and a tap at the same time). This worked magnificantly.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Add tap and pan gesture recognizers to handle game input.
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSidePan:)];
        panRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.leftSideView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLeftSideLongPress:)];
        longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
        longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
        [self.leftSideView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
    }
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSidePan:)];
        panRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [self.rightSideView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

        UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleRightSideLongPress:)];
        longPressRecognizer.delegate = self;
        longPressRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.0;
        [self.rightSideView addGestureRecognizer:longPressRecognizer];
    }
}

- (void)handleLeftSidePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    [self handleGameScreenPan:panRecognizer withVirtualController:&g_iPadVirtualController[0]];
}

- (void)handleRightSidePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    [self handleGameScreenPan:panRecognizer withVirtualController:&g_iPadVirtualController[1]];
}

- (void)handleLeftSideLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressRecognizer
{
    [self handleGameScreenLongPress:longPressRecognizer withVirtualController:&g_iPadVirtualController[0]];
}

- (void)handleRightSideLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)longPressRecognizer
{
    [self handleGameScreenLongPress:longPressRecognizer withVirtualController:&g_iPadVirtualController[1]];
}
```